# Send Exceptions up the Call Stack from Different Modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I want to send a custom exception from different modules to the top calling module and to display the module name, line number and function name from the exception source. The traceback code is from Doug Hellmann's [book/website](https://pymotw.com/3/traceback/index.html).

In the code below, the line number (`linenum`) in the result `call_b.py              :11:c():` is where `MyException` is raised not where the exception occurred (`print(1/0`) on line 9). How do you send the correct exception information up the stack to the calling module?

As an aside, in the traceback loop, how do you get hold of just the last entry `call_b.py              :11:c():`?

File `call.py`:

```
import os
import sys
import traceback
from call_b import b

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def a():
    try:
        b()
    except (Exception, MyException) as e:
        # https://pymotw.com/3/traceback/index.html
        template = '{filename:<23}:{linenum}:{funcname}:\n    {source}'

        print('format_exception():')
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        for tb_info in traceback.extract_tb(exc_tb):
            filename, linenum, funcname, source = tb_info
            if funcname != '<module>':
                funcname = funcname + '()'
            print(template.format(
                filename=os.path.basename(filename),
                linenum=linenum,
                funcname=funcname,
                source=source))

a()
```

File `call_b.py`:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def b():
    c()

def c():
    try:
        print(1/0)
    except Exception as e:
        raise MyException
```

`> python call.py`:

```
format_exception():
call.py                :11:a():
    b()
call_b.py              :5:b():
    c()
call_b.py              :11:c():
    raise MyException
```

Comment: You’re replacing the original exception with your own… You can retain the original context with `raise … from e`…‽

Comment: If you want the original exception to be exposed, then why do you interfere and catch it yourself?  If you remove your try/except/raise code, this does exactly what you ask

Comment: @deceze Ah, it works with raise e. Plus, I understand now. Thank-you so much. If you want to create an Answer then it can be accepted.